# Implement Ajax live search in google sheet for data entry

Tags: ajax, search, google-sheets, live, instantsearch.js

I have a spreadsheet of few thousands row with column that has multi word sentences so its not possible to remember exact name and at which sequence the words appear
such as "Cambridge international physics coursebook for a level"
As google sheets built in search don't allow partial words search like in websites.
I have made a workaround using filter function+regexmatch+split function to filter out the exact cell
[see my example search](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NsAf6xHmQo7Bjfkb6iciJxXaGOzTg6jGxb6BfUvn4l0/edit?usp=sharing)

but after that, I have to manually search it using crtl+F ,as filter function don't allow me to edit filtered data,its very tedious.
How can i implement live ajax search in google sheet or is their any workaround or other software i should use for my data entry and modification purpose.

And can I use algolia instantsearch like feature for editing my sheet.

Comment: Could you maybe explain what is exactly what you want? (Extracting a text from a range, looking for matches in a column, etc) I think that using Apps Script or some form of regular expression could be more useful for your case. [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: what I wish to accomplish is
1. LIVE AJAX SEARCH WITH EDITING CELL CAPABILITY
google sheet don't allow editable query,is their any way i can make query editable

Answer (score 1):

Take in mind that Apps Script has [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), using this AJAX approach will make your quotas expire very quickly. Try to minimize the execution of scripts with this function.

You can just use [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) in combination with a [custom sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars), in there call the server function that you want to execute. If you space the executions to let's say 1 every 2-3 seconds you should be good.